# What is the result of this in scheme: (cdr '((a b c d)))

Tags: list, scheme, racket, cdr

Isn't it supposed to be (a b c d) ??

When I try it on Racket it gives me () .

Answer (score 1):

`'((a b c d))` is a list, containing only one element, that is the four-element list `(a b c d)`. So if you get the `car` of it, you obtain as result `(a b c d)`, while the `cdr` produces correctly the empty list `()`.

Answer (score 1):

How would you create such a list using `cons`?

```
(cons (cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c (cons 'd '()))))
      '())
```

or

```
(cons '(a b c d) '())
```

[`cdr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._cdr%29%29) returns the second element of the given pair, so it returns `'()`.

Comment: Thank you actually I didn't want to create a list with '() and '(a b c d) I just wanted to understand the outcome but it's still useful thanks again !

Comment: @mariokebab The point is that to answer the question "What is this list's `cdr`?", you can alternatively ask "How could I build this list with `cons`?". Whatever the second argument to `cons` was, that's what the `cdr` is.